# Is there a native way to show Emoji in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Twitter often uses Emoji, but they don't show well in Chrome. Up until a few minutes ago, I used Chromoji. However, today it hijacked my browser while going through Stack Overflow to show me an advertisement screen. fortunately, I use an adblocker, but it still showed me a near-empty screen with a line of text at the top saying "Supporting chromoji". Obviously, if they're going to be so obnoxious about wanting money, I don't want anything to do with them. I uninstalled it right away. However, this means that part of twitter is broken for me...

Is there a native alternative for adding emoji support to Chrome? I could go with another extension, but I have no guarantee that it won't pull the same trick.

Apparently, I spoke too soon and you can disable those advertisements. I'll do that instead. I'm still interested in an alternative method.

Comment: @Ramhound Currently 38.

Comment: What version of Chrome?  Anyways if you want native support you will have to wait for it.  You will have to find another extension that provides this functionality.  IE11 on Windows 8.1 supports them, that is always a solution, the touch screen keyboard even supports them provided a Windows Store application is installed.

Comment: @Ramhound My version is 38.0.2125.111 m.

Comment: See my answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1352307/707676

Answer (score 0):

open developer tools =>

Right-click: "emoji & symbols" option.