# How can I insert emoji in chrome except copying from elsewhere?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, unicode

Is there a way to insert emoji in Chrome efficiently? There are some extensions, but they mostly look like spyware (you can enter emoji, but we'll spy on your browsing history). Do you know a reliable extension or some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update 4/2019*:

**In Windows 10 build 1809 there is now the "Emoji" context menu item. It can be brought up by either from the context menu or by <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>**

The context menu appears in any editable field in any application.

---

*Original answer*

I ended up using https://browsernative.com/emoji/ as a bookmark. It's simple enough. Although I'd prefer having a overlay popup window that would insert the emoji directly to the form. I'm actually thinking about creating such extension myself. Opensource, so anyone can see that I don't collect personal information of any kind.

I also found `chrome://flags/#enable-emoji-context-menu` which I turned on but the context menu did not appear.

[image: emoji context menu flag in chrome]

Answer (score 1):

[HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) `&entity_name;` or `&#entity_number;` where `entity_number` would be Unicode codepoint in decimal or `x`-prefixed hexadecimal value, e.g.

```
&#128536;  &#x1F618;  &#9785;  &#x2639;  &spades;  &#9824;  &#x2660;
```

😘  😘  ☹  ☹  ♠  ♠  ♠

Resources: [HTML Symbol Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp) or [Emoji Unicode Tables](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) etc.

Comment: Thanks. Valid answer, but not really efficient. Remembering 100+ ids is not very practical :(

Comment: Yes, I know:) [Then, try all, choose the best…](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/emoji?hl=en-GB)

Answer (score 0):

right click: "emojis & symbols" option after opening developer tools: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

or in top menu: Edit -> "Emoji & Symbols" option

In mac os: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>

ps: this shortcut is also available in atom, if you're using that editor.

Comment: Does not work on Windows. Mac specific, though still useful for Mac users.

Comment: did you find how to do it in windows 10/7? let's put it here so other people may benifit from it!

Comment: I'm using https://superuser.com/a/1150883/55905 in the meantime...

Answer (score 0):

Chrome now has naitive support for inserting Emojis in the right click menu.
Displaying Emojis has been supported since version 41.

Right click in a textbox, and select "*Emoji*":

[image: right click]

Then go crazy:

[image: emoji menu]

---

I'm running Chrome 68.0.3340.106.

[image: chrome version]

Comment: I'm running `Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and the Emoji menu item is missing. (Windows 10)

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro | 
OS Version:                10.0.16299 N/A Build 16299